# jquery focus and focusout, is this considered acceptable markup?

Tags: jquery, focus, semantic-markup, focusout

I'm learning / trying to be better in jQuery. I was wondering if the following is acceptable markup, or is there a cleaner, smaller way to accomplish the same?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#searchwrapper .searchbox').focus(function(e) {
            $('#searchwrapper .searchbox_submit').css('color', '#999999'); 
        }
    );
    $('#searchwrapper .searchbox').focusout(function(e) {
            $('#searchwrapper .searchbox_submit').css('color', '#dddddd'); 
        }
    );
});
```

**EDIT / SOLUTION**

Thanks to [Arun P Johny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny) and [senyor Toni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1416980/senyor-toni) the js I ended up using.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var swap_color = $('#searchwrapper .searchbox_submit');
    $('#searchwrapper .searchbox').focus(function(e) {
            swap_color.css('color', '#999999'); 
        }
    ).blur(function(e) {
            swap_color.css('color', '#dddddd'); 
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks ok, probably you can improve the usage of selectors by caching it.

1. Chain the event handlers
2. Cache the selector `$('#searchwrapper .searchbox_submit')` using a variable

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var searchbox_submit = $('#searchwrapper .searchbox_submit');
    $('#searchwrapper .searchbox').focus(function(e) {
            searchbox_submit.css('color', '#999999'); 
        }
    ).focusout(function(e) {
            searchbox_submit.css('color', '#dddddd'); 
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: yes, thanks... I was playing with that but was not working due a semantic error. With your example I now know what I did wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can chain to make a more optimized jquery sentence, and use `blur` instead of `focusout` since this one bubbles the focus out event and you probably don't need event bubbling,
like that:

```
$('#searchwrapper .searchbox').focus(function(e) {
        $('#searchwrapper .searchbox_submit').css('color', '#999999'); 
    }
).blur(function(e) {
        $('#searchwrapper .searchbox_submit').css('color', '#dddddd'); 
    }
);
```

Also you should store the jquery selectors that will be used in the future in a javascript variable, like this:

```
var selector = $('#searchwrapper .searchbox_submit');
```

then call `css`:

```
$('#searchwrapper .searchbox').focus(function(e) {
        selector.css('color', '#999999'); 
    }
).blur(function(e) {
        selector.css('color', '#dddddd'); 
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks, gave 1 up due I used the blur instead of the focusout. thanks.